# Fatal error: Call to a member function setActive() on a non-object

Tags: magento

I am getting the following error on the backend of Magento:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setActive() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/pro-pin.ca/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php on line 82
```

I've gone through the community forum, but found out that this was due to the magic slider or lightbox extensions. I haven't had this problem on any other server.

Any help please..

Answer (score 1):

Based on line number I'm primarily running a different version of Magento than you, but if you look at `Action.php`, you'll see something like this

```
protected function _setActiveMenu($menuPath)
{
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('menu')->setActive($menuPath);
    return $this;
}
```

The call to

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('menu')
```

is supposed to return a block object, but if your system it isn't.  The most likely culprit here in one of your extensions is removing the block named menu from your layout, **or** one of your developers fiddled with some layout and/or Core files.

In your development environment remove all your modules.  If the problem goes away, re-enable until it starts again and you'll know which module is causing you a problem.  If the problem doesn't go away, grab a fresh copy of Magento and start diffing files.

Answer (score 1):

I removed all the extension and tried but no success, but when i replaced the adminhtml layout files it worked.
The layout files directory was adminhtml/default/default/layout/

Answer (score 0):

Before deleting you module, try manually clearing the cache files.

go to var/cache and delete all the directories in the folder (if prompted with any denied messages, skip those items). Be patient there may be a few thousand cache files. When finished, try and login again, 9 out of 10 times you will be able to.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to remove local.xml file and to re-install your store(no data loss -This installs the magento engine without removing your data.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
```

in `index.php` or increase memory to your php.ini.